Django query to sum the n largest related values
I have a db that tracks players' scores over a number of games. I want to create a leaderboard using each player's 4 highest scoring games.
Here are my models:
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)

class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Score(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["player", "event", "game"]

I've tried using a subquery, but it seems like my slice is being ignored and the sum returned is all of the player's scores, not just their top 4 scores:
scores = Score.objects.filter(player=OuterRef('pk'), event=myEvent).order_by('-score')[:4]
scores = scores.annotate(total=Func(F("score"), function="SUM")).values('total')
leaders = Players.objects.annotate(total=Subquery(scores)).order_by('-total')

Any ideas on how to get the subquery working? Or a better way to approach the problem?

What database do you use?

No idea if it can be done in one query or even if this idea will work, but what about get the single highest scoring game for each player with the first query. Then repeat the query with .exclude( pk__in=[...] ) to get the second-highest. Add these to the exclude list to get the third highest ... Four queries.

Maybe this will work:
from django.db.models import Max, Q
score = Score.objects.filter(palyer__name={p})\
 .annotate(max_a=Max('score', filter=Q(game__name={a}))\
 .annotate(max_b=Max('score', filter=Q(game__name={b}))

